# NSFetchedResultsController result filtering

Tags: iphone, database, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Is there an easy way to filter the results provided by the `NSFetchedResultsController`?

I am using the standard Core Data Template which works very well for simple tables.

What I have is a `UITableVIew` with a `UISegmentedControl` with two categories, one that displays all and one that when selected should display only events what were created today.

I have been able to accomplish this in two different tableViews (so i know how to use NSPredicate, that is not my problem; the problem is combining it into a single tableView).

I know you cannot change the fetchRequest once the `NSFetchedResultsController` has been created.

So I can guess that I will have to create a new `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Has anyone implemented something like this or have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must create a new `NSFetchedResultsController` – after all, changing the fetch request would basically amount to reinitializing it from scratch anyways (due to the operations that `NSFetchedResultsController` performs behind-the-scenes on the fetched data).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used NSFetchedResultsController much as my codebase predates it, however in the past i have just fired off an NSFetechedResults request with a different predicate depending on the state of the segmentedControl.